# PDF Parser PHP Library Not Working

Tags: php, pdf, composer-php, pdf-parsing

I'm using the [PDF Parser](http://www.pdfparser.org/) PHP library to parse the text from several PDFs. It works perfectly for a majority of these, but seems to just timeout and stop working for certain PDFs.

This is the code I'm using (straight from their demo page):

```
<?php

include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf    = $parser->parseFile('document.php');

$text = $pdf->getText();
echo $text;

?>
```

When I replace 'document.pdf' with the URL to [this file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52819455/working.pdf), it works perfectly as expected.

However, when I replace 'document.pdf' with the URL to [this file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52819455/not-working.pdf), it just times out with a blank page.

Any ideas why it would work for one file and not the other?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: not all pdfs have text in them. sometimes the pdfs are just PICTURES of text...

Comment: @MarcB That being said, I can copy and paste the text from the PDF I linked to. Wouldn't that mean it's real text and not just a picture?

Comment: Did you checked your PHP error logs? You may try to enable it in the script too: `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);` A blank page leads to a fatal error.

Comment: @Setasign Thanks! It looks like the issue is with the PHP Parser library itself. There doesn't seem to be any exception handling, so when a PDF that's unreadable (or made up of only images) is passed through, it creates a null string, which causes a fatal error instead of generating an error message like I would have expected.

Comment: @user994585 .. did you find answer?

Answer (score 0):

yes this "ghost" error I saw it too, nothing even in `error_log`, nor tripped in `try catch` very hard to diagnose if you increase the `memory_limit` in `php.ini` it goes away, it's either something to do with the bad garbage collection on the developers part or ballooning - i think the latter because my loop failed after 4 pdf's but when I quadrupled available ram it didn't fail after 60